# HttpClientFactory with default Polly policy handler registration and injection with SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, simple-injector, polly

Per https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#extending-the-convenience-addtransienthttperrorpolicy-definition I can see policies are added with a name.

```
var httpClientOptions = HttpPolicyExtensions
    .HandleTransientHttpError()
    .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(6,
        retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));

services.AddHttpClient(/*have to add a name*/)
    .AddPolicyHandler(httpClientOptions);
```

I am using Simple Injector in parallel to the .net dependency injection, and I inject the http client factory into my consuming classes as below:

```
public PolygonIoApiFetcher(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
    this.client = clientFactory.CreateClient(/* what to use here */);    
}
```

My issue is that I have a number of functions written in other libraries that won't necessarily have the client factory policy name shared between libaries.

Furthermore, to keep things simple I would probably want a single poly retry policy for all my `HttpClient` created by the factory - is there any way for `IHttpClientFactory` to return a default `HttpClient` with the default poly policy applied?

I do not want to use a typed registration either per https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/654, and I need to control the lifetime of the object via the `IHttpClientFactory` injected as opposed to the `HttpClient` being injected into the consuming class.

In summary, the wiring/injection at startup should determine the policy injected and easily rewired/changed, and not by the consuming class.

I have provided what I have done so far, but pointers appreciated if this is, as i suspect, an already solved problem.

**Idea below - create a wrapper class**

The parameterless `HttpClient CreateClient(this IHttpClientFactory factory)` extension method from `System.Net.Http` cannot be overridden, so I thought to use the wrapper class and manually select the policy during injection:

```
public interface IPollyHttpClientFactory
{
    HttpClient CreateClient();
}

public class PollyHttpClientFactoryWrapper
{
    private readonly string policyName;
    private readonly Container container;

    public PollyHttpClientFactoryWrapper(
        string policyName, Container container)
    {
        this.policyName = policyName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.container = container ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    public HttpClient CreateClient()
    {
        return this.container
            .GetInstance<IHttpClientFactory>()
            .CreateClient(this.policyName);
    }
}
```

And use during registration:

```
Container.RegisterSingleton<IHistoricalAggregates>(
    () => new PolygonIoApiFetcher(
        new PollyHttpClientFactoryWrapper("RetryPolicy", Container),
        Container.GetInstance<ApiKeys>().PolygonIoApiKey));
```

The only "issue" is my classes would need to use the `IPollyHttpClientFactory` interface, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I can give you a satisfying answer, but here's an idea for a possible implementation. You can make the `IPollyHttpClientFactory` conditional, in a way that each consumer gets its own version. This can be done using the `RegisterConditional` method. For instance:

```cs
var container = new Container();

container.RegisterSingleton<IHistoricalAggregates, PolygonIoApiFetcher>();

container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IPollyHttpClientFactory),
    c => typeof(PollyHttpClientFactory<>)
             .MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => true);

container.MapPolicy<PolygonIoApiFetcher>("RetryPolicy");
```

Here, `MapPolicy` is a custom extension method:

```cs
public static class ContainerPolicyExtensions
{
    public static void MapPolicy<TImplementation>(
        this Container container, string policyName) =>
        container.RegisterInstance(new Policy<TImplementation>(policyName));
}
```

`Policy<>` is a simple generic data object that allows holding the name of the policy to use for the `HttpClient` (you can add any additional data relevant to creating http clients to this policy class):

```cs
public sealed record Policy<TConsumer>(string PolicyName);
```

`PollyHttpClientFactory<>` is the generic implementation of `IPollyHttpClientFactory`. It gets injected with the relevant `Policy<T>` and it is, therefore, able to create a http client specific to its consumer:

```cs
public record PollyHttpClientFactory<TConsumer>(
    IHttpClientFactory Factory, Policy<TConsumer> Policy)
    : IPollyHttpClientFactory
{
    public HttpClient CreateClient() =>
        this.Factory.CreateClient(Policy.PolicyName);
}
```

Optionally, you could combine the `Register` and `MapPolicy` methods into a single extension method:

```cs
public static void RegisterWithPolicy<TService, TImplementation>(
    this Container container, string policyName, Lifestyle lifestyle = null)
    where TService : class
    where TImplementation : class, TService
{
    if (lifestyle is null) container.Register<TService, TImplementation>();
    else container.Register<TService, TImplementation>(lifestyle);
    container.MapPolicy<TImplementation>(policyName);
}
```

This allows you to make the registration and mapping in one swoop:

```cs
container.RegisterWithPolicy<IHistoricalAggregates, PolygonIoApiFetcher>(
    "RetryPolicy",
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

One last note. In your question you call the `IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient` method from *within* the constructor, and store the client in the consumer. This is typically not a good idea, because it could possibly allow the client to live for a long time and defeats the purpose of the `IHttpClientFactory`. Instead, store the `IPollyHttpClientFactory` (or `IHttpClientFactory`) in a private field and only call its `CreateClient` method from within the methods of the consumer, and dispose the client at the end of the method.